# Call a javascript function infinitely

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new to JS , and I just wonder if it's possible to create kind of a loop with 2 functions .. example:

```
function a() {
    var myvar =1;
    b();
}
function b(){
    var myvar =2;
    a();
}
a();
```

I get this result when I try to run it "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Haven't you tried it?

Comment: (Of course, the code you've shown here is an *infinite* loop, which won't do anything good, and cause a stack overflow given its recursive implementation)

Comment: It will throw a RangeError due to stack overflow.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax, so you won’t get a `SyntaxError` with this code. If you do, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Xufox , is it bcs I run this inside a <script></script> in HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this, but there are a few things to keep in mind:

- This may cause a memory leak, and can slow your user's browser
- Looping between two functions without a delay will exceed maximum stack size

You could use `setInterval` of course, but it's not very flexible.

A function I like to use is written a little like this:

```
(function(delay, callback){
    var loop = function(){
        callback();
        setTimeout(loop, delay);
    }; loop();
})(1000, function(){console.log('Hello World!')});
```

It logs `'Hello World!'` every 1000ms, or 1 second.

Another way to do this is by simply referencing itself in a timeout, like this:

```
function sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello World!');
    setTimeout(sayHello, 1000);
}; sayHello();
```

..or better yet, a permanent solution:

```
function loopFunction(delay, callback){
    var loop = function(){
        callback();
        setTimeout(loop, delay);
    }; loop();
};

loopFunction(1000, function(){console.log('Hello World!')});
```

To call two functions every other interval, you could either create a toggle switch, or call the second function a little bit later with `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're trying is very risky for a potential memory leak.

The method you should use is by calling `setInterval`. Where 3000 means the number milliseconds before each iteration.

```
setInterval(
    function(){ 
        alert("Hello"); 
    }, 
    3000
);
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp